# If an angle $\theta$ is not constructable, then $\cos\theta$ is not constructable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, geometric-construction

Claim: if an angle $\theta$ is not constructable, then $\cos\theta$ is not constructable.

I am at the very end of a proof, and I suspect this claim is true and it would help me very much in this proof. Does anyone have any insight on this? I've been trying for a bit, drawing it out, and I cannot think of a method to prove it. Any guidance is appreciated.

---

Edit:
I have since tried something that seems to make sense to me. I use a previous result that the square roots of positive constructable numbers are constructable and that the constructable numbers form a number field. So I instead prove the contrapositive. I assume $\cos\theta$ is constructable. I draw a line and mark $\cos\theta$ on it. Since $\cos\theta$ is constructable, it follows that $\sqrt{1 - \cos^2\theta}$ is constructable. I construct a bisector at one end of $\cos\theta$ and mark $\sqrt{1 - \cos^2\theta}$ on it so that they are end-to-end. Then, using straightedge, connect their opposite ends. So the non-right angle which is next to $\cos\theta$ must be $\theta$.

---

Edit: Thanks for the help. I understand now.

Comment: If you can construct $\cos theta$ then you can construct a right triangle with one leg $|\cos \theta|$ and a hypotenuse of $1.$ Then the angle of this is $\theta$ or $\pi-\theta.$ In either event, it is easy to construct $\theta$ from this right triangle/.

Answer (score 4):

Prove the contrapositive. Suppose $\cos\theta$ is constructible. Then in right triangle $ABC$ with $\angle B$ right, $AC=1$ and $BC=\cos\theta$, $\angle C=\theta$.

Comment: I think I am missing something really obvious here. How do I construct the hypotenuse when I only know that $\cos\theta$ is constructable? Or is it assumed that we are taking the approach I just edited in?

Comment: @Euler'sFriend Draw the perpendicular to $BC$ at $B$. Then draw a circle of unit radius centred on $C$. (We always assume $1$ is comstructible.)

Answer (score 2):

If you *could* construct $\cos \theta$ then to get theta all that's needed is to intersect a vertical line with unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unit circle and the $x$ axis (certainly both constructable) then $\cos \theta$ will be the length along the $x$ axis where if you dropped perpendicular (constructable) from the point where the  $\angle \theta$ intersects to circle.

Likewise if you raised a perpendicular (constructable) from $\cos \theta$ you'd get the point of intersection.  And it's a matter of constructing a line from the point of intersection to the origin (constructable) to get $\angle \theta$.

So $\angle \theta$ is constructable $\iff \cos \theta$ is constructable.